# Getting unread mail from exchange web services via PHP

Tags: php, soap, exchangewebservices, php-ews

How do you get all unread mail in a users' exchange mailbox using PHP while using [this class](http://code.google.com/p/php-ews/) ?

I figured to first list a folders contents like this:

```
$ews = new ExchangeWebServices("mailserver.domain.local", "user", "pass");

$request = new EWSType_FindFolderType();
$request->FolderShape = new EWSType_FolderResponseShapeType();
$request->FolderShape->BaseShape = EWSType_DefaultShapeNamesType::DEFAULT_PROPERTIES;

$request->ParentFolderIds = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType();
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId = new EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdType();
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Id = EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdNameType::INBOX;

$request->Traversal = new EWSType_FolderQueryTraversalType();

$result = $ews->FindFolder($request);

var_dump($result);
```

Only then I get this error:

`Catchable fatal error:  Object of class EWSType_FolderQueryTraversalType could not be converted to string`

Is there anybody with experience with this class that can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I do know that a string has to be passed, but it seems the class has just 3 constants without any functions or other properties..

Comment: New location for the php-ews library is : https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, in above example I had to use

```
$request->Traversal = EWSType_FolderQueryTraversalType::DEEP;
```

Since it only had the 3 constants.

But posting it here since I think it might be useful for anyone else looking to do the same, listing all mail in your inbox goes as follows:

```
$ews = new ExchangeWebServices("mailserver.domain.local", "user", "pass");

$request = new EWSType_FindItemType();
$request->ItemShape = new EWSType_ItemResponseShapeType();
$request->ItemShape->BaseShape = EWSType_DefaultShapeNamesType::DEFAULT_PROPERTIES;

$request->ParentFolderIds = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType();
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId = new EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdType();
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Id = EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdNameType::INBOX;

$request->Traversal = EWSType_ItemQueryTraversalType::SHALLOW;

$result = $ews->FindItem($request);
```

Comment: Can you get this to work on Linux or are you running it on Windows?

Comment: I used this on Windows, did not try it on Linux, but, I'll have to in the future, if you try it, please let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: I was getting null results, but my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529388/php-ews-class-library-always-returns-null/ was answered and it turns out the account I was using did not have enough privilege