# PHP EWS OOF (Out of Office) Request

Tags: php, exchangewebservices

I am using the PHP Exchange Web Services Library ( https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews ) to currently retrieve User availibility without issue.  What I would like to do is retrieve an Out of Office response (If set) for users and can not seem to figure out how to setup the request properly.  What I have so far:

```
$ews = new ExchangeWebServices();
$request = new EWSType_GetUserOofSettingsRequest();
$request->Mailbox->Address = 'TEstUser@Test.com';
$ewsResponse = $ews->GetUserOofSettings($request);
```

All I am getting back however is:

```
stdClass Object
(
[ResponseMessage] => stdClass Object
    (
        [MessageText] => Connection did not succeed. Try again later.
        [ResponseCode] => ErrorConnectionFailed
        [DescriptiveLinkKey] => 0
        [ResponseClass] => Error
    )

)
```

Any thoughts on how to setup this request properly?

**EDIT**
As I have received a few emails from users I felt I would update this issue accordingly.  I no longer have access to an Exchange environment to test this code with so any updates would be helpful!

The following code comes from my ldapAdapter file and can be used in the following manner:

```
$request = createEWSRequest();
$request->MailboxDataArray->MailboxData->Email->Address = $email;
$ewsResponse = $ews->GetUserAvailability($request);
$fbtInfo = getFreeBusyTime();


private function getFreeBusyTime() {
    if (isset($this->ewsResponse->FreeBusyResponseArray->FreeBusyResponse->FreeBusyView->CalendarEventArray)) {
        if (is_array($this->ewsResponse->FreeBusyResponseArray->FreeBusyResponse->FreeBusyView->CalendarEventArray->CalendarEvent)) {
            $this->nextMeetingStart = $this->ewsResponse->FreeBusyResponseArray->FreeBusyResponse->FreeBusyView->CalendarEventArray->CalendarEvent[0]->StartTime;
            $this->nextMeetingEnd = $this->ewsResponse->FreeBusyResponseArray->FreeBusyResponse->FreeBusyView->CalendarEventArray->CalendarEvent[0]->EndTime;
            $this->busyType = $this->ewsResponse->FreeBusyResponseArray->FreeBusyResponse->FreeBusyView->CalendarEventArray->CalendarEvent[0]->BusyType;
        } else {
            $this->nextMeetingStart = $this->ewsResponse->FreeBusyResponseArray->FreeBusyResponse->FreeBusyView->CalendarEventArray->CalendarEvent->StartTime;
            $this->nextMeetingEnd = $this->ewsResponse->FreeBusyResponseArray->FreeBusyResponse->FreeBusyView->CalendarEventArray->CalendarEvent->EndTime;
            $this->busyType = $this->ewsResponse->FreeBusyResponseArray->FreeBusyResponse->FreeBusyView->CalendarEventArray->CalendarEvent->BusyType;
        }
        $this->meetingScheduled = true;

        $date = new DateTime($this->nextMeetingStart, new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
        $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
        $this->nextMeetingStart = $date->format(DateTime::W3C);

        $date = new DateTime($this->nextMeetingEnd, new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
        $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
        $this->nextMeetingEnd = $date->format(DateTime::W3C);
    } else {
        $this->meetingScheduled = false;
        $this->nextMeetingStart = false;
        $this->nextMeetingEnd = false;
        $this->busyType = false;
    }
}

private function createEWSRequest() {
    $request = new EWSType_GetUserAvailabilityRequestType();
    $request->TimeZone = new EWSType_SerializableTimeZone();
    $request->TimeZone->Bias = '360';
    $request->TimeZone->StandardTime = new EWSType_SerializableTimeZoneTime();
    $request->TimeZone->StandardTime->Bias = '0';
    $request->TimeZone->StandardTime->Time = '02:00:00';
    $request->TimeZone->StandardTime->DayOrder = '5';
    $request->TimeZone->StandardTime->Month = '1';
    $request->TimeZone->StandardTime->DayOfWeek = 'Sunday';
    $request->TimeZone->DaylightTime->Bias = '-60';
    $request->TimeZone->DaylightTime->Time = '02:00:00';
    $request->TimeZone->DaylightTime->DayOrder = '1';
    $request->TimeZone->DaylightTime->Month = '4';
    $request->TimeZone->DaylightTime->DayOfWeek = 'Sunday';
    $request->MailboxDataArray = new EWSType_ArrayOfMailboxData();
    $request->MailboxDataArray->MailboxData = new EWSType_MailboxData();
    $request->MailboxDataArray->MailboxData->Email = new EWSType_EmailAddress();
    $request->MailboxDataArray->MailboxData->Email->RoutingType = 'SMTP';
    $request->MailboxDataArray->MailboxData->AttendeeType = 'Required';
    $request->MailboxDataArray->MailboxData->ExcludeConflicts = false;
    $request->FreeBusyViewOptions = new EWSType_FreeBusyViewOptionsType();
    $request->FreeBusyViewOptions->TimeWindow = new EWSType_Duration();
    $request->FreeBusyViewOptions->MergedFreeBusyIntervalInMinutes = '30';
    $request->FreeBusyViewOptions->RequestedView = 'FreeBusy';

    $date = new DateTime();
    $this->startDate = date_format($date, DateTime::W3C);

    $date->modify('+8 hours');
    $this->endDate = date_format($date, DateTime::W3C);

    $request->FreeBusyViewOptions->TimeWindow->StartTime = $this->startDate; //'2013-04-01T15:00:00';
    $request->FreeBusyViewOptions->TimeWindow->EndTime = $this->endDate; //'2013-04-20T18:00:00';

    return $request;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529388/php-ews-class-library-always-returns-null). Seems like you have to specify the exchange server you try to gather information from plus your access credentials. Hope that helps ;)

Comment: The request doesn't return null, it returns a valid object, however not what I am looking for.  Any other request I have created and tried (general availability request) works and works well, it is only the OOF status that is having issues.